# Navigation bar visible for 3 seconds when turning on the screen

Tags: android

When turning on the phone's screen the navigation bar becomes visible for about 3 seconds even in immersive full screen activities. Is there a way to turn that off or keep it from showing?

I have a lock screen where it interferes with the swipe if someone starts at the bottom of the screen, not to mention a dialer app that has half of the call button covered for 3 seconds where an accidental tap takes the user home...

Comment: Post the relevant code for that.

Comment: It seems to be an Android thing. It doesn't matter that I set it with a full screen theme, android:windowFullscreen, or in the activity like: getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);